# Как отображать "логовую" информацию на activity с обновлением в реальном времени?

Tags: android

Как лучше отобразить что-то вроде логов на активити? Нажимаешь кнопку, выполняется http запрос и лог его выполнения показывается на активити в реальном времени. Что-то вроде:

```
Соединение...Ок 
Посыл запроса...Ок
Получение ответа...Ок
```

То есть, как в консоли.

Какой control надо использовать? Как это сделать так, чтобы GUI не зависал, то есть одновременно с посылкой запроса писался лог.

Comment: `ListView`, нет? Запрос может работать только паралельно, в отдельном потоке, т. к. работа с сетью в главном потоке в Android запрещена.

Comment: @metalurgus, разве простой TextView с "\n" не подойдет?

Comment: нет, если лог будет достаточно большой, упадет ваше приложение с `OOM` из за `TextView` размером 10000х1080 при его рендеринге. Вы попробуйте вложить просто для примера `TextView` в `ScrollView`, и вставить в него, например, первый том *Война и мир*, и посмотрите, что произойдет

Comment: много не будет, думаю, строчек 20, пусть даже 50. ну пусть даже 500, то есть таких "действие - статус" 500 раз. и все.

Comment: Ну так и делайте с `TextView`, зачем вы спрашиваете?

Comment: @metalurgus, ну так уточняю, понимаешь ли. вдруг, есть лучший способ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что операции с сетью необходимо выполнять в другом потоке, но из другого потока нельзя обновить инфу в Activity,  а всё потому, что данные операции выполняются строго в главном потоке, чтобы это можно было сделать можно наследовать свой **AsynkTask** и выполнять в методе **doInBackground()** основную операцию с сетью, далее в методе **onProgressUpdate()** можно получать данные из метода **doInBackground()** и обновлять UI, для этого необходимо вызывать в **doInBackground()** метод **publishProgress()**, а по окончанию возвращаете значение в методе **doInBackground()** от получаете его в методе **onPostExecute()**, который тоже может обновить Activity, почитайте [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/150-urok-87-asynctask-parametry-promezhutochnye-rezultaty.html)

Answer (score 1):

Сделать можно разными способами, но самый простой это `ProgressDialog` и `AsyncTask`. Гуглите в этом направлении

Comment: мне также нужно отобразить это на activity.

Comment: Человек вам всё правильно написал, в AyncTask вы также сможете обновить Activity.

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, я знаю, только я сейчас спрашиваю не об этом. В каком контроле **отобразить** текст логов?

Comment: TextView Вам не подходит?

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, я пока не знаю.

Comment: Тогда я вам говорю, что подходит, если вы собираетесь делать, как указали в своём вопросе